# Converting to polar coordinates: Why is the square root not taken in this case?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I am given an equation of a cylinder $z = x^2+(y-1)^2=1$

When graphed, the circle is centered at (0,1). When taking the integral of this cylinder, I need to find the value for $r$, which I can do by rewriting the equation as follows:

$x^2+y^2-2y+1=1 \Longrightarrow x^2+y^2 = 2y$

Then, converting to polar notation, it turns into

$r^2 = 2sin(\theta)$

Now, when taking the integral, I've been instructed to integrate from $0$ to $r$, so if $r^2 = 16$ I would integrate from $0$ to $4$.

However, in this case the solution says that I should integrate from $0$ to $2sin(\theta)$

I understand where the $2sin(\theta)$ came from, but shouldn't it be $sqrt(2sin(\theta))$ instead? Why am I not taking the root if it is the value of $r^2$ like I do when it has a constant radius?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really close!

It is true that
$$x^2+y^2-2y+1=1 \Longrightarrow x^2+y^2 = 2y$$

As you say, polar coordinates give us

$$r^2 = x^2 + y^2$$

but polar coordinates give 
$$ y = \mathbf r \sin(\theta) $$

**not** 
$$y=\sin(\theta) $$

So we get 
$$r^2 = 2\mathbf r \sin(\theta)$$

and by dividing by $r$
$$r = 2 \sin(\theta)$$